# JSON throwing out an error

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection

I'm getting a json parse error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 2.)
```

Which means there is some problem in jSON response. But I'm facing a weird situation like I'm not getting this error when I'm using the local host url. If I'm using the staging server URL to fetch the json I'm getting this error. But the fact is the same file has been migrated to the staging server.

When I checked url in browser I'm getting same response for both the urls;.

This is my response

```
[
  {
    "ClinicId": 15,
    "ClinicNumber": "45-001",
    "Name": "TBD Utah",
    "PCName": "",
    "Address": "",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "",
    "State": "UT        ",
    "Zipcode": "",
    "RegionId": 15,
    "Latitude": 0.0,
    "Longitude": 0.0,
    "MetroId": 0,
    "CoopId": 0,
    "PublicEmail": "",
    "PublicPhoneNumber": "",
    "ActualPhoneNumber": "",
    "ClinicOpenDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "ClinicUrl": "",
    "Notes": ""
  },
  {
    ------
  },
  {
    ------
  },
]
```

This is the way i'm fetching the data

```
     NSString *str=@"http://192.2.200.167:84/api/Clinic/ClinicsByLatandLong?latitude=36.778261&longitude=-119.417932&apiKey=E9F5958F-C4BE-4D81-8649-F385205F0684";

    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:aUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                           delegate:self];
   if (connection) {
        responseData=[NSMutableData data];
    }
```

Comment: It's a string encoding problem. you need to use UITF8StringEncoding with json response.

Answer (score 1):

Before you parse the response, I'd suggest you examine it (in code, not in a web browser), e.g.:

```
NSLog(@"responseData = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

I'd wager the response is not what you think it is. Either the web server is reporting some error, or perhaps there is a problem in your `didReceiveData`.

You haven't shared enough for us to comment on your `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods, but this `NSLog` will help you confirm that the JSON response is actually what you expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rob. But I have solved the issue by adding json flags in NSJSONSerialization class